# How to optimize a SVD recommender regarding number of factors?

Tags: svd, recommender-system

I am using R to do recommendation based on [pureSVD](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://labs.yahoo.com/files/recsys2010_submission_150.pdf&ei=AHNJU5_dIpDz8QWCtICABA&usg=AFQjCNEj1yVEhckuaxjU0u62_8dnJO3MNA&sig2=FQEdXWDoxZym9RiMbpXr6g&bvm=bv.64542518,d.dGc&cad=rjt). It is basically to choose the number of factors and then SVD the user-item matrix and then restore the matrix and provide top-N recommendations for each user. **I am wondering how the number of factors should be chosen?** How about other SVD based latent factor models to deal with this?

Should I set a selected range of numbers, then use an iteration and perform evaluation (precision/recall) for each run and finally find out which number of the best? Or can I optimize the result to find the best number? Because I can not figure out what expression or cost function I should apply derivative to so as to minimize the cost function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of factors is considered a hyperparameter of the model. Your intuition is correct: you should perform a [hyperparameter search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html), fitting and evaluating your model with different number of factors, and select the one that performs best on your test set.

Comment: some may argue that optimization should be conducted on a dev set disjoint from the test set, and that the test set should be used only at the end for evaluating the final model.

Comment: Yes. These are commonly known as the test and validation sets. The link to sklearn that I provided approaches this by using cross-validation.

Comment: so the model that should be selected is not the one that performs best on the test set (as you stated), but on the dev set